# jQuery AJAX parse JSON with many node levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following code in this

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"url",
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"jsonp",
        success:function(data){
            i=0;
            $.each(data, function(index, item){
                console.log(item["channel"].item[i].title);
                i++;
            });
        }
     });
```

I was wondering where I might be going wrong? I seem to only be able to write to the console the first "title" in the JSON object. When in fact there are 10 items.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: In an each loop with jQuery, you don't need the `i`, it does that automagically.

Comment: I had added that in as it was not incrementing. I see now from @undefined that it was because I was iterating through the data object which is 1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are iterating through the `data` object which has only one property(*data* property), so the `each` handler is executed only once, you should iterate through the inner `item` property directly.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"...",
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    success:function(data){
        $.each(data.data.channel.item, function(index, item){
            console.log(item.title);
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QN6Rn/